# How to add IndexController in admin

Tags: magento

```
<?php
class Main_Contacts_AdminhelloController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {

        $this->loadLayout();

    //create a text block with the name of "example-block"
        $block = $this->getLayout()
        ->createBlock('core/text', 'example-block')
        ->setText('<h1>This is a text block</h1>');

        $this->_addContent($block);

        $this->_setActiveMenu('main')->renderLayout();      


    }
}
```

if i wrote this code it is okay, but when i use setFormAction instead of createBlock it causes error and i want to use this method in admin section.

IndexController.php

```
public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('contactForm')
            ->setFormAction( Mage::getUrl('*/*/post') );

        $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
```

How can i use this code please anyone tell me.

Comment: it would help if you tell us the error...

Comment: Call to a member function setFormAction() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\community\Main\Contacts\controllers\AdminhelloController.php on line 9

Comment: so obviously your block has not been found by name or alias "contactForm"...

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this way i think this is only way  i know 
**class magento_SimpleContact_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action**

```
public function indexAction()
{
$this->loadLayout();
    $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
        'Mage_Core_Block_Template',
        'magento.simple_contact',
        array(
            'template' => 'magento/simple_contact.phtml'
        )
    );
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
    //$this->getLayout()->getBlock('right')->insert($block, 'catalog.compare.sidebar', true);
    $this->_initLayoutMessages('core/session');
    $this->renderLayout();**
```

in my contact file **app/design/frontend/default/default/template/magento/simple_contact.phtml**